# why does "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" sometimes fail to parse an HTML body?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The library I'm using is: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser v1.5.0](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

with some urls, it's str_get_html() and file_get_html() calls will return false.  For example:

```
 $html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/');
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: use their finance api rather than scraping the page, problem solved.

Comment: @Dagon, your assuming I'm trying to scrape financial data; but what I'm trying to do is scrape the pages <meta> data.  Plus that is just one recent example I came across.  Other urls do the same.

Comment: I would highly suggest using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML DOM parser [supports invalid HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm).
But the issue can be with loading yahoo page, all kinds of forwarding on the page... everything that cURL can cope with.
So fast, dirty and probably the worst way to handle the situation is to use the workaround - loading page contents with cURL and then parsing the variable with the code with Simple HTML DOM.

Something like this:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$search_url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/';

function bCurl($url) {

    $cookie_file = "cookie1.txt";

    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
    $header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
    $header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
    $header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
    $header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
    $header[] = 'Pragma: ';
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $result;
}

$result = bCurl($search_url);

$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load($result);   

$keywords = $html->find("meta[name=keywords]",0)->getAttribute('content');

print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Proper solution would probably be analyzing yahoo finance page, checking what's going on there, analyzing forwarding and anti-scraping mechanisms, javascript and flash objects... but hey, we all like instant, fast and dirty solutions like this one, right? ;)